# É correto o primeiro "ou" em "Há duas possibilidades: ou isso ou aquilo"?

Tags: conjunções

Como em:

> Das duas uma: algo ou está errado ou está faltando.

Seria correto esse primeiro "ou"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sim, *ou . . . ou* é correto. Significa a mesma coisa que apenas *ou*.

É uma *locução disjuntiva*, ou seja uma *conjunçao alternativa*; exprime exclusão ou alternativa.  Outras locuções disjuntivas são:

- *ora . . . ora*
- *já . . . já*
- *quer . . . quer*
- *seja . . . seja*
- *seja . . . ou*
- *nem . . . nem*
- *quando . . . quando*

Da [Norma Culta: Gramática Online da Língua Portuguesa](http://www.normaculta.com.br/oracoes-coordenadas/):

> **Oração coordenada sindética alternativa**: transmite uma ideia de alternância em relação à oração anterior. É obrigatório o uso de vírgulas entre orações coordenadas sindéticas alternativas. Caso haja apenas uma oração coordenada sindética alternativa o uso da vírgula é opcional. São utilizadas conjunções coordenativas alternativas ou locuções conjuncionais coordenativas alternativas: ou, **ou...ou**, já…já, ora...ora, quer...quer, seja...seja, nem…nem, etc.

Da [Gramática Priberam](http://www.flip.pt/flip-on-line/gramatica/morfologia-partes-do-discurso/conjuncao.aspx):

> As conjunções coordenativas subdividem-se em **copulativas, disjuntivas, adversativas** e **conclusivas**.
>
> 1. As conjunções copulativas servem apenas para ligar palavras e orações:
>
>    *e, nem, não só... mas também*.
> 2. As ***conjunções disjuntivas*** exprimem exclusão ou alternativa:
>
>    *ou, quer... quer, ora... ora, seja... seja, quando... quando, já... já*.
> 3. As conjunções adversativas indicam oposição ou restrição de sentido nas expressões:
>
>    *mas, porém, todavia, contudo*.
> 4. As conjunções conclusivas exprimem uma conclusão tirada da oração anterior:
>
>    *logo, portanto, pois, por conseguinte*.

Comment: `ou` ... `ou` é necessariamente uma disjunção exclusiva, enquanto `ou` pode não ser (depende do contexto).

Comment: @Artefacto Tens razão. Obrigado.

Comment: "falou e disse" (brazilian slang) +1

Comment: Só uma nota: O nome da figura de linguagem obtida ao repetir a conjunção antes de cada elemento coordenado chama-se [polissíndeto](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poliss%C3%ADndeto) (por exemplo: *"**Nem** veio, **nem** viu, **nem** venceu."*). E difere do assíndoto, no qual conjunções são omitidas (e.g.: *"Vim, vi, venci!"*); e do síndoto, no qual só se usa conjunção antes do último elemento (isto é, a forma normal que usamos regularmente, e.g.: *"Foi, viu, **e** venceu!"*).